# WebDriver Navigation Issues

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, selenium

I am attempting to click on a button in a web interface, however normal click functions fail so I have attempted to execute javascript, but to no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated.

The button is called THISBUTTON

[image]

**Code**

```
<div class="tab_middle clearfix" id="tab_middle2">
   <div class="tab_icon" id="tab_icon2"></div>
   <div class="tab_title editable" id="tab_title2" data="{&quot;columns&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;allowConfig&quot;:true,&quot;allowClose&quot;:true,&quot;fixedColumn&quot;:null,&quot;eventCode&quot;:&quot;null&quot;,&quot;pageNumber&quot;:2,&quot;isPreset&quot;:false,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;THISBUTTON&quot;,&quot;boxWidth&quot;:&quot;1220:209&quot;,&quot;autoFit&quot;:true,&quot;isSlideShow&quot;:0,&quot;intIntervalSlideShow&quot;:10,&quot;isReadOnly&quot;:false,&quot;isDisabled&quot;:false}">
      <span class="tab_title_span show" id="tab_title_span2">THISBUTTON</span><!--{"columns":"2","allowConfig":true,"allowClose":true,"fixedColumn":null,"eventCode":"null","pageNumber":2,"isPreset":false,"name":"THISBUTTON","boxWidth":"1220:209","autoFit":true,"isSlideShow":0,"intIntervalSlideShow":10,"isReadOnly":false,"isDisabled":false}--><input type="text" id="tab_title_input2" class="tab_title_input hide" maxlength="64">
   </div>
   <div class="tab_controls" id="tab_controls2">
      <div class="tab_more_btn" id="tab_more_btn2"></div>
      <div class="tab_options_btn" id="tab_options_btn2"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tab_more_menu" id="tab_more_menu2">
      <div class="tab_more_menu_unit" id="tab_more_menu_rename2">Rename</div>
      <div class="tab_more_menu_unit" id="tab_more_menu_chg_layout2">Change Layout</div>
      <div class="tab_close_btn tab_more_menu_unit" id="tab_close_btn2">Delete</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have attempted the following:

```
clickme = browser.find_elements_by_id('tab_title_span2')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickme[0])
```

Comment: can you reattempt with this `clickme = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_title_span2')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickme)` and let me know

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to be clickable? It seems pretty straightforward using the id. Are you sure the id is unique on the page?

Comment: I have already attmpted it this way @Tuks. `Error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: arguments[0].click is not a function`

Comment: Thanks for the down votes btw, helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may works with action chains.

```
this_button = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_title_span2')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(this_button).click(this_button).perform()
```

Comment: This worked after modifying your suggestion to `this_button = browser.find_element_by_id('tab_title_span2')
webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(this_button).click(this_button).perform()`

Comment: Thanks so does the move_to_element statement shift focus to the element? Apologies just wanting to understand this correctly

Comment: Move to element is for mouse over on element and some time element may get focus as well.